# How do you return all the words in a text file (once per word) in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, unique

I have to return each word once meaning if a word is repeated in the file, it only gets printed one time, not twice- hence the unique part. I need help figuring out how to do that. I have it to where it is in alphabetical order but I can't figure out to have the words only print once and not in a list.

Here is my code:

```
file = input("Enter the input file name:")
f = open(file, 'r')
words = f.read()
unique_words = sorted(words.split(' '))
for word in words:
    if word == word:
        value = word
        unique_words.remove(value)
    else:
        print(word)
```

Comment: `word == word` is always `True`...

Comment: @Marcos Not always, try this one: `float('nan') == float('nan')`

Comment: @U10-Forward `word` is a string variable, nothing related to floating-point representation.

Comment: you want `for word in unique_words:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of errors in such a small program. Let's list them, shall we.

```
...
unique_words = sorted(words.split(' '))
```

Looking good so far. But then you run into several logical problems:

```
for word in words:
```

If you print out what `word` is, you will see it is a *letter*. That is because you are iterating over the original `words` string. You meant to use `unique_words` here, the *list* that you prepared just a line earlier.

```
if word == word:
```

This cannot fail. The same string is always equal to the same string. (It's hard to imagine otherwise; but do note that this only true for *strings*. Other objects may have this curious property.) You probably meant `if word in words`, and with the earlier correction, *more* probably `if word in unique_words`. That is a superfluous test – you are already looping *over* `unique_words` so yeah, each `word` already is in `unique_words`. So even *more* probably you meant something like "does this word occur *more* than once in my list?"

It is possible you attempted this as it is because in other languages, a double `for` loop is needed to check. Python has [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html); you could have used `if unique_words.count(word) > 1` here. But you *should* not. Let's see why.

```
    value = word
    unique_words.remove(value)
```

This is a huge issue. This would *change* the list `unique_words` here while it is looped upon. That is a big no-no, because the internal loop counters (the original length of `unique_words` is off, then.

That looping problem is introduced by my earlier fix for your code, so let's assume you intended this instead:

```
for word in words.split():
    if word in unique_words:
        value = word
        unique_words.remove(value)
    else:
        print(word)
```

– notice the small adjustment to the first line. No error but it still does not work (as intended), because now it prints nothing. That is because you are now removing *every* word from `unique_list` ...

You can solve that as per above, by using `count` again:

```
if unique_words.count(word) > 1:
```

and then finally you get only one occurrence printed per word.

Since the *only* problem is getting a list of unique words, then there is a simple and very Pythonic solution: use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). The one unique thing about a `set`, compared to a `list`, is that every item is only *allowed* to occur only once. If you convert a `list` to a `set`, all duplicates magically disappear.

```
print (set(unique_words))
>>> {'alphabetical', 'printed', 'I', 'out', 'list.', 'that.', ...
```

But what happened to the sort order? As it is, the contents of a set is not stored in an ordered list (due to the way the string *hashes* work). So, the trick is to first eliminate duplicates and then sort:

```
unique_words = sorted(set(words.split(' ')))
print (unique_words)
```

where no further loops are necessary and `words` is just your original input string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set to remove duplicates, and then pass that to the builtin `sorted()` function.

```
file = input("Enter the input file name:")
with open(file) as f:
    for word in sorted(set(f.read().split())):
        print(word)
```

Here "word" means groups of characters separated by whitespace. Depending on your file, this might be good enough. If you need to filter punctuation, you can use a regex instead of `.split()`. You could also coerce to lowercase if you don't want an uppercase version counting as a different word. Depends on your file and what exactly you are trying to do.

```
import re
file = input("Enter the input file name:")
with open(file) as f:
    for word in sorted(set(re.findall('\w+', f.read().lower()))):
        print(word)
```

The `\w+` will match "word characters", while `.lower()` converts the whole string read from the file into lowercase.

Comment: In what Python version do lists have a `sorted` method?

Comment: @HeapOverflow sorry, I mixed up the builtin `sorted()` with the `list.sort()` method. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: I get an error that says 'NoneType' object is not iterable when using the first code you provided.

Comment: Odd that you didn't get an error when you tested it.

Comment: @Outsider Try reloading the page. The corrected version worked when I tested it. Can you tell me which function had the error?